# How to remove event handlers in svg elements?

Tags: javascript, svg

Take mouseover, and a function "foo" for instance. "this" is the svg element.

```
this.mouseover(foo); // adds handler
this.unmouseover(foo); // removes handler
```

But what if I'm doing:

```
this.mouseover(function(parameter){foo(parameter);}); // say I need to pass a parameter
```

Can I remove this handler?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in any way I recommend.

I you must, there is a way to access an anonymous function from within itself. This is deprecated and wont work in strict mode/ES5+:

```
var anonymousFn = null;
this.mouseover(function(parameter) {
  foo(parameter);
  anonymousFn = arguments.callee;
  // now anonymousFn has a reference to the annymous function
});
```

See: [`arguments.callee`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee)

Comment: Oh well. I was hoping to be able to avoid having to declare one more function... but it's not likely.

Answer (score 0):

No; you don't have a reference left to the anonymous function.

One way around this would be to declare the function just above your `mouseover` call:

```
var param = parameter;
var foobar = function(){foo(param);
this.mouseover(foobar);
this.unmouseover(foobar);
```